# Very bizarre and challenging error in a "read-it-and-weep" program in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. This is what I have going on so far:

```
def next(I):

if I == 0:
    return 0
else:
    s_I = str(I)
    result_s = ''
    result_i = 0
    while True:

        if len(s_I) !=0:
            count = 1
            marker = s_I[0]
            for x in range(0, (len(s_I)-1)):
                if s_I[x] == s_I[x+1] and s_I[x] == marker:
                    count = count + 1
            result_s = result_s + str(count) + marker

            s_I = s_I[count:]
            continue
        else:
            break

    result_i = int(result_s)
    print(result_i)
```

So for those who aren't familiar with read-it-and-weep, if you give the number 1111, it will output 41. You read the integer, and the next integer in the sequence is what comes after you read it again. So for example, the first couple are: 1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221, 312211, 13112221, etc... SO, here's my issue:

Whenever my I has a repeat of a number that's not right next to it, such as 1211, or 11122211, it doesn't work. The 1's get counted again for some reason, and everything gets weird.

For example:

- In: I = 1211
- In: next(I)
- Out: 2121

When it should be 111221. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop logic is wrong. First off, range goes up to, but not including n. You loop should be `for x in range(1,len(S_I)):`

The 1 is because you already started your count at 1, so if you start at 0 you will double count the first element. This should be what is causing this error, you are double counting every number.

Comment: Ah, fair point. The reason I had the range up to -1 was due to the indexing error that occurred in the if statement below it. I've changed to what you've suggested, as it makes more sense, but now I'm struggling on the proper if statement as to now go out of range.

Comment: You could check against the last character instead of the next.

Comment: "The simplest path is often the easiest." Thanks for that. My output still isn't matching the desired output—I.E. the in and out statements I have above are still the way they are. The double counting is still occurring unfortunately. I'll keep working at it and see what I can muster. If you have any other ideas, let me know, but you've already been a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can of course do this much simpler using `itertools.groupby()`:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> n = 1211
>>> [(str(len(list(i))), c) for c, i in it.groupby(str(n))]
[('1', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('2', '1')]
```

Now just flatten and `join()`:

```
>>> ''.join(it.chain.from_iterable((str(len(list(i))), c) for c, i in it.groupby(str(n))))
'111221'
```

Comment: Hey AChampion, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I've been told not to import any libraries other than the basic few.